# Attach ebs volume to the EC2 instance based on availablity_zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need some help on getting volumes attached to the EC2 instances using terraform. I want to attach the volumes in a availability_zone to the EC2 instances in the same availability_zone .

I am not putting in the code to create subnets. I think it is not needed but I can if it matters.

This is the code to create volumes in each of the availability_zone against each subnet

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "demo_ebs_volume" {
for_each = aws_subnet.public_subnets 
availability_zone = each.value.availability_zone 
size = 1 
encrypted = true
}
```

I also have created aws_instance in each of subnets.

```
resource "aws_instance" "demo_instance_public" {
for_each      = aws_subnet.public_subnets
ami = "ami-0cc87e5027adcdca8"
instance_type = "t2.micro"
subnet_id = each.value.id                
vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.demo_security_group.id]
}
```

Now I want to attach the volumes to the EC2 instances so that the availability_zone matches.

I am trying like this:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "demo_ebs_attachement" {
for_each = aws_ebs_volume.demo_ebs_volume
device_name = "/dev/xvda"
volume_id   = each.value.id
instance_id = aws_instance.demo_instance_public[index(aws_instance.demo_instance_public.*.availability_zone,each.value.availability_zone)].id
}
```

I am getting errors.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

instance_id = aws_instance.demo_instance_public[index(aws_instance.demo_instance_public.*.availability_zone,each.value.availability_zone)].id

Error: This object does not have an attribute named "availability_zone".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `aws_subnet.public_subnets` in `for_each` for both volumes and instances. This means that they will have the **same key**. So you can use this fact, and use `each.key` to join both of them:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "demo_ebs_attachement" {
   for_each    = aws_ebs_volume.demo_ebs_volume
   device_name = "/dev/xvda"
   volume_id   = each.value.id
   instance_id = aws_instance.demo_instance_public[each.key].id
}
```